# Passing decimal parameter

Tags: apex

I am using a managed app. I am supposed to pass a decimal to a method. If I just send a decimal i.e. 22.0 it works. If I create a Decimal variable and pass it, it gives me an error:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature:

To be clear
This works:

```
method(22.0);
```

This doesn't work

```
Decimal d;
method(d);
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening and if there is a workaround?

Comment: Are you giving `d` a value?

Comment: Can you pls share `method(d)`. What is the type of this variable accept.. If it is manage package class still you can check the method It accept which type of arguments.

Comment: Yes. I was just illustrating

Answer (score 1):

If I will pass a decimal value, I would choose the Double data type.

`Double d;`

`method(d);`

Comment: I tried your suggestion by using a double but no change.

Comment: @ApexN-u-b Can you please post what is inside in your "method" ? This problem only occur when the method does not exist or the data pass to the method is not compatible with what is declared.

Comment: It is a bad idea to get into the habit of mixing double and decimal, particularly if you are dealing with money where you want exact values that preserve and define a known number of decimal places.

Comment: ... but on reflection your change may be the solution if the signature of the method does use a double.

Answer (score 0):

I fully agree what Keith has mentioned apart from that check if you are passing a string instead of decimal. You can use the following decimal method-

```
Decimal dx = Decimal.valueOf(d);
method(dx);
```